# How can I use basic authentication and form based authentication spring security

Tags: spring, forms, security, authentication

So I am looking for a programmatic configuration way of using form based authentication and basic authentication on the same resource.  What I mean is if I fill out the login form and authenticate I should be able to use the site.  At the same time if I authentication using basic auth I should be able to access the same resources.  Is it possible?  I was even thinking maybe using a DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint where if there is a certain header specified it will use basic otherwise it will use form based login.  Anyway any help would be appreciated?

Comment: Bit confusing but to clarify are you asking you want to have form based login authentication and a equivalent to AD/SSO login capability at same time?

Comment: Why do you want this in the first place?

Comment: What you want is certainly possible. Your application should support both cookie and basic authentication.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look at the `request-matcher-ref` attribute of the `http` element in the [Spring Security Current Reference Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#nsa-http-attributes). It enables you to specify custom conditions under which a particular `FilterChain` will be used or not. For example, you can determine which authentication mechanism to use, according to the host header of incoming request.

```
<bean id="customMatcher1" class="org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.ELRequestMatcher">
    <constructor-arg value="hasHeader('host', 'stackoverflow.com')"/>
</bean>
<bean id="customMatcher2" class="org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.ELRequestMatcher">
    <constructor-arg value="hasHeader('host', 'careers.stackoverflow.com')"/>
</bean>
<sec:http request-matcher-ref="customMatcher1">
    <sec:http-basic />
</sec:http>
<sec:http request-matcher-ref="customMatcher2">
    <sec:form-login />
</sec:http>
```

Look and choose one of existing implementations or look and write own implementation of the [`RequestMatcher`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.2.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/util/matcher/RequestMatcher.html) interface.